# How to Set Details Of file in Win7 by Shell object?

Tags: shell, vbscript, windows-7

I have this below `vbscript` to get one of the details of a file (we get by View->Choose Details in active folder window) which will retrieve Title detail/property of that file.

```
folder = "D:\StrongBox\Desktop\CSS The Complete Guide\01 Getting Started"
filename = "001 Introduction.mp4"
Set ShellObj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set FolderObj = ShellObj.Namespace(folder)
MsgBox FolderObj.GetDetailsOf(FolderObj.Parsename(filename), 21)
```

How to set the detail of the the file?

I could not find a function like **SetDetailsOf**.

Comment: What details specifically are you trying to set? And when asking a code related question, you should always include a tag for the language you're using. It helps get it in front of people who can answer it, and it makes it easier for future readers who are searching for results to find as well.

Comment: Each file format has its own way of expressing details. You need to study the file format. Some details are harder to change that others. For example, changing the bitrate is a lot harder than changing the title.

Comment: @Ken White, I try to set the same property (Title property) for the file i.e. Its current title is 'Video1' and I try to change it to its file name and as you suggested I've added `vbscript` tag.

Comment: AFAIK what you're asking is not possible, at least not via the `Shell.Application` object or other general scripting APIs. [Related](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/scriptcenter/en-US/8246b1f5-b11b-4d5e-8a07-1bcd5f94852c/how-to-write-extended-properties).